# Or-tools Boolean expression

Tags: boolean, or-tools

I am new into or-tools and Boolean expression. I have search but I cannot find anyone describing this small problem.

I need

```
d = (Teams[r,g,m,t]==1) && (Teams[r,g,m+1,op]==1)
model.Add(WhoVsWho[t,op]==1).OnlyEnforceIf(d)
```

Any suggestions how I write this?

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple enforcement literals, the semantic is that they must all be true for the constraint to be enforced:

```
model.Add(WhoVsWho[t,op]==1).OnlyEnforceIf(Teams[r,g,m,t], Teams[r,g,m+1,op])
```

but actually, it is better to stay in the Boolean world:

```
model.AddBoolOr(Teams[r,g,m,t].Not(), Teams[r,g,m+1,op].Not(), WhoVsWho[t,op])
```

which is equivalent to:

```
model.AddBoolAnd(WhoVsWho[t,op]).OnlyEnforceIf(Teams[r,g,m,t], Teams[r,g,m+1,op])
```

Comment: Thank you. Very help full. Explanation is clear